# Move category by row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following values in a column.
We assume that we know what the categories are, and there are many products with different names. The order is strict and there is an id column. The only things we know are the names of the categories and that the products that follow each category are part of that category.

```
|Column                        |ID|
|------------------------------|--|
|Category-Phones               |1 |
|Apple iPhone 15 Pro Max 256GB |2 |
|Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra 256GB|3 |
|Motorola Razr+ 256GB          |4 |
|Category-Wearables            |5 |
|Google Pixel Watch            |6 |
|Fitbit Sense 2                |7 |
|Garmin Venu 3 with Silicone B.|8 |
|Category-Phone Accessories    |9 |
|Apple MagSafe Battery Pack    |10|
|Tile Mate Essential (2022) 4P.|11|
|Apple Clear Case iPhone 11Pro |12|
```

and I would like to get the data in two columns:

```
|Categories                        |Products                         |
|----------------------------------|---------------------------------|
|Category-Phones                   |Apple iPhone 15 Pro Max 256GB    |
|Category-Phones                   |Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra 256GB   |
|Category-Phones                   |Motorola Razr+ 256GB             |
|Category-Wearables                |Google Pixel Watch               |
|Category-Wearables                |Fitbit Sense 2                   |
|Category-Wearables                |Garmin Venu 3 with Silicone Band |
|Category-Mobile Phone Accessories |Apple MagSafe Battery Pack       |
|Category-Mobile Phone Accessories |Apple Clear Case for iPhone 11Pro|
|Category-Mobile Phone Accessories |Tile Mate Essential (2022) 4-Pack|
```

How could I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: I'm assuming those were meant to be formatted as tables? Please format them as such. You can read how to [Organize information as tables](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/organizing-information-with-tables)

Comment: Are there any more columns, for example a sequential ID number?

Comment: yes, there is an id column

Comment: YOu should include that in your sample data then, @andreicpu .

Comment: There is no internal ordering of the rows in a SQL table, so from what you've shown, there is no way to know what products are supposed to be nested under which Category.

Comment: Do you have the data that were used to populate the database so that you can start again with a better database deisgn?

Comment: There needs to be a mapping between categories and products. Relying on id order is a breach of relational database principles.

Comment: I have updated the data. Is better ?

Comment: The only things we know are the names of the categories and that the products that follow each category are part of that category.

Comment: That's fundamentally bad design, breaching relational database principles. Can it be fixed?

Comment: This is the report I received from a program. I have no choice.

Comment: Report? Why not look in the table directly?

Comment: I take the data from a report, process it and import it into another program.

Comment: It would be easier in excel. You'll have to import it in to a database to do it there, by which time you'd have done it manually anyway.

Comment: The data is voluminous, here I have only specified the essence of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still indicative of a serious schema problem. Hopefully you intend to use the solution to resolve that issue?

Assuming you have the ID column, and it's always true that the rows that do not start with 'Category-' are products that belong to the preceding category:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Name VARCHAR(50), ID INT);
INSERT INTO @Table (Name, ID) VALUES
('Category-Phones',1), ('Apple iPhone 15 Pro Max 256GB',2), ('Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra 256GB',3), ('Motorola Razr+ 256GB',4),
('Category-Wearables',5), ('Google Pixel Watch',6), ('Fitbit Sense 2',7), ('Garmin Venu 3 with Silicone B.',8),
('Category-Phone Accessories',9), ('Apple MagSafe Battery Pack',10), ('Tile Mate Essential (2022) 4P.',11), ('Apple Clear Case iPhone 11Pro ',12);

;WITH Categories AS (
SELECT ID AS CategoryID, LEAD(ID,1) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT ID)) AS NextCategory, Name AS CategoryName
  FROM @Table t
 WHERE Name LIKE 'Category-%'
)

SELECT CategoryID, p.ID AS ProductID, c.CategoryName, p.Name AS ProductName
  FROM Categories c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table p
      ON p.ID > c.CategoryID
      AND (p.ID < c.NextCategory OR c.NextCategory IS NULL);
```

So here we find the category rows (1, 5 and 9) (in the `CTE`) and then join back to the table to get all rows that are greater than the category ID and less than the NEXT category ID.

This will only work when the conditions are true, and is BEGGING to have a proper relationship defined for it. Hopefully you are just trying to sanitize the data to achieve that.

| CategoryID | ProductID | CategoryName | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Category-Phones | Apple iPhone 15 Pro Max 256GB |
| 1 | 3 | Category-Phones | Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra 256GB |
| 1 | 4 | Category-Phones | Motorola Razr+ 256GB |
| 5 | 6 | Category-Wearables | Google Pixel Watch |
| 5 | 7 | Category-Wearables | Fitbit Sense 2 |
| 5 | 8 | Category-Wearables | Garmin Venu 3 with Silicone B. |
| 9 | 10 | Category-Phone Accessories | Apple MagSafe Battery Pack |
| 9 | 11 | Category-Phone Accessories | Tile Mate Essential (2022) 4P. |
| 9 | 12 | Category-Phone Accessories | Apple Clear Case iPhone 11Pro |

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like a more general solution.

Comment: Altered to meet your new requirements and example data.

Comment: Very good solution. Thank you. Can it also work like this: OVER (ORDER BY ID)?

Comment: Yes, the parenthesis are left over from the previous version that had no column to order by.

Answer (score 0):

First, data in a SQL Server table has no implied order, so you need to unambiguously define one. I have added an IDENTITY value to your data for this purpose.

From there, selecting the products is straight forward using a `LIKE` operator. As for choosing the associated Category, you can use the `OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY ...)` pattern to select the *best matching row* - in this case the closest preceding "Category" row.

```
SELECT P.Name AS ProductName, C.CategoryName
FROM Products P
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 C.Name AS CategoryName
    FROM Products C
    WHERE C.Id < P.Id
    AND C.Name LIKE 'Category%'
    ORDER BY C.Id DESC
) C
WHERE P.Name LIKE 'Product%'
ORDER BY Id
```

If a product appears before the first category, the above would return a null CategoryName.

Results:

| ProductName | CategoryName |
| --- | --- |
| Product1 | Category1 |
| product2 | Category1 |
| Product3 | Category1 |
| Product4 | Category2 |
| Product5 | Category2 |
| Product6 | Category2 |
| Product7 | Category3 |
| Product8 | Category3 |
| Product9 | Category3 |

See [this db<>query](https://dbfiddle.uk/HYv4LbO2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like a more general solution.

Comment: @andreicpu - It is a bit rude to change the finish line after the community has already worked to provide solutions. Nevertheless, the above approach works perfectly well with your new sample data. The only modification needed is to replace `LIKE `Product%'` with `NOT LIKE 'Category%'`. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VzIyhr2z). You can tweak the column names and result column order as needed.

Comment: I will grant that I believe that Patrick Hurst's solution may have better performance for large data sets, since it performs only two passes through the data and uses category lookup, instead or repeated search-back operations.

Comment: It's my first question here and I didn't know that it's not okay to modify the question. I just wanted to provide more information. Your solution is really simpler. Thank you for answer.

Comment: It's nice that you are honest and that you made an effort to evaluate the best solution.

Comment: @andreicpu - I probably came off sounding too harsh. I apologize for that. And of course questions can be improved as they are being worked as needed to clarify requirements and provide more context or details. I hope that whichever solution you run with works well for you.

Comment: Thanks again. You are very kind and a good consultant.